# comportamiento raro de columnas en un datagridview cambian de posicion sus valores

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

tengo un datagridview con sus columnas llamadas IdNota,Nombre,Descripcion,Importe,Fecha
pasa algo muy curioso al momento yo de hacer un update o un insert hasta ahi todo bien pero si yo quiero despues de hacer dicha accion seleccionar otra fila y hacer otro edit o un delete me marca un error de formato y esto pasa por que depurando me di cuenta que los valores cambian de posicion de columnas es decir si por ejemplo en la columna id me deberia de mostrar un numero en lugar de eso me muestra el nombre de la persona , al principio utilizaba algo como "GridClientesCredito.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;" pero despues en base a otra pregunta que hizo otro usuario en lugar de poner la posicion puse el nombre de la columna pero auna si los valores cambian , por que pasa esto ? y como lo puedo solucionar? agradezco su ayuda adjunto imagenes y codigo

```
  private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Id = GridClientesCredito.CurrentRow.Cells["IdNota"].Value;
        string nombre = GridClientesCredito.CurrentRow.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
        string descripcion = GridClientesCredito.CurrentRow.Cells["Descripcion"].Value.ToString();
        int importe = Convert.ToInt32(GridClientesCredito.CurrentRow.Cells["Importe"].Value.ToString());
        string fecha = GridClientesCredito.CurrentRow.Cells["Fecha"].Value.ToString();
        //string QueryUpdate = "UPDATE tblNotasClientes SET Descripcion = '" + descripcion + "' , Importe = " + importe + " , Fecha = '" + fecha + "' WHERE IdNota = " + Id + " ";
        //ado.executaSQL(QueryUpdate);
        //MessageBox.Show("se actualizo correctamente");
        //Mostrar(nombre);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ahora mismo hice un insert y todo bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y ahora como pueden observar en el registro del 6 de enero voy a modificar el importe y dar click en el boton de editar y vean lo que pasara

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ok hare una aclaracion tengo la columna id invisible y eso tiene mucho que ver el por que no la enuentra pero no la quiero mostrar ya que el id no es necesario que el usuario final lo vea y otra cosa curiosa si yo selecciono una fila y sin editar nada y doy click y depurando si me trae el valor de esa columna aun que sea invisible

Comment: Asegúrate de seleccionar la fila al momento de Editar, de lo contrario no encontrará los valores. antes de asignar los valores a las variables, valida la fila seleccionada con : if (GridClientesCredito.SelectedRows.Count != 0)

Comment: ok muchas gracias tienes razon estoy haciendo una  prueba para validar si me selecciona la fila pero al parecer no muchas gracias ya es una pista mas para llegar a la solucion